# How to filter tree to common parent

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a tree (with checkbox) that appears as follows.

```
A
    A1 
        A11 
            A111 (selected)
            A112 (selected)
            A113 
        B11
            B111 (selected)
            B112
```

I want to filter this to return as follows, since `A1` is the common parent for selected nodes

```
A1
   A11
       A111
       A112
    B11
       B111
```

Tree is a hierarchy with root nodes and their children:

```
public class Node
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  public Node Parent;
  public List<Node> Children;
}
```

Basically , this is a tree structure in the UI. Based on what user selects (checkbox), i'll have to find the common parent and display the *resultant* tree.

Comment: From the Tree hierarchy / Node class posted, a child node has no reference to the parent. If that's the case, then you'll have to recursively search the parent node and all children to find the selected nodes, assuming there is some field/property on a Node identifying it as selected; perhaps identifying their branch depth of all selected nodes and then using the highest depth - 1 to find the parent node.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Pl look at my edited class.

Comment: What are the metrics for the "common parent"? To me, it should be "A" since they all fall under A--how did you come to "A1"

Comment: it's the immediate common parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the basic idea for finding the common ancestor of a set of nodes:

1. For each selected node, get the set of nodes including itself and its ancestors;
2. Find the intersection of all of these nodes;
3. Of those, take the node with the highest depth.

So, how do we do this?

Let's start by writing a property to get the list of ancestors for a `Node`.  (We need the "and self" part to handle the situation where only a single node is selected -- in that case the common node is that node itself and I'm assuming you don't want the parent.  If I'm wrong and you want it to find the parent anyway, you can change this property to only return strict ancestors, but then you'll need to add a special case for the root node, which has no ancestors.)

```
public List<Node> AncestorsAndSelf
{
    get
    {
        List<Node> list = new List<Node> { this };
        Node p = Parent;
        while (p != null)
        {
            list.Add(p);
            p = p.Parent;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

There is already an [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) method in the `System.Linq` namespace which can find the intersection of a set of items, so we've got step 2 covered with that.

For the third step we need a way to get the depth of a node.  But since we already have the `AncestorsAndSelf` property written, this is trivial:

```
public int Depth
{
    get { return AncestorsAndSelf.Count; }
}
```

So now that we have all the pieces, we can write a method to find the common ancestor of a selected set of nodes:

```
public static Node FindClosestCommonAncestor(IEnumerable<Node> selectedNodes)
{
    IEnumerable<Node> commonAncestors = selectedNodes.First().AncestorsAndSelf;
    foreach (Node n in selectedNodes.Skip(1))
    {
        commonAncestors = commonAncestors.Intersect(n.AncestorsAndSelf);
    }
    return commonAncestors.OrderByDescending(n => n.Depth).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Once we have the common ancestor, we need a way to print out the subtree.  This can be done with a simple recursive method like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return ToString("");
}

private string ToString(string indent)
{
    string s = indent + Name + "\r\n";
    foreach (Node child in Children)
    {
        s += child.ToString(indent + "    ");
    }
    return s;
}
```

Here is a demo showing the whole thing in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cl7JGp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of root-level nodes called `nodes` you can simply do:

```
var node = nodes.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Name == "A1");
if (null != node)
    return node.Children;
return new List<Node>(); 
// or you can return null if you'd prefer
```

Comment: this is not gonna work, I'll have to find a `common` parent nodes based on what selected at the leaf level. It's not based on name "A1" ( "A1" is simply a name for illustration , I do not even know "A1" is the common parent, I'll have to "find" it based on what is selected by the user.

Comment: I missed the "selected" portion of your question. I thought at the time it was an awfully easy question for somebody to be asking. There was an old Joel on Software blog posting about tree structures and how they managed their task trees and kept them performant. I'll see if I can find it because it's a really elegant solution using the IDs of the nodes that you might find useful.